# Magento2 Cant override checkout js file billing-address.js

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs

It seems like a dumb question that was answered a lot here but I cant get it to work.

I want to override `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js` the file is physically under `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js`.

Ive copied the file to my `<theme>/web/js/components/checkout/billing-address.js` and added the configuration to my `requirejs-config.js`:

```
map: {
        "*": {
            "dropdownDialog":       "js/components/dropdownDialog",
            "sidebar":              "js/components/sidebar",
            "catalogAddToCart":     "js/components/catalog-add-to-cart",
            "cookieNotices":        "js/components/cookieNotices",
            "loader":               "js/components/loader",
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": 
                                             "js/components/checkout/billing-address",
        }
    }
```

But the file is not overriden. I still geht the original from module-checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared my caches but the file was still cached on the server in static folder in an old version.
I had to manually remove it so magento re deploys it.

Ive run:

```
rm pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/lang/js/components/checkout/billing-address.js
```