# Magento 2 How to override "\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js" in our custom module?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, billing-address, address

I want to disable "New Address" option from billing address drop down. here i got the code to disable it.

we just need to comment the below code : **addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);** and it will disable the option. but I need to override this file in my custom module and need to comment that code.

How can i override "billing-address.js" in my custom module?

Thanks.

Comment: This may help to you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203668/magento2-cant-override-checkout-js-file-billing-address-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you need to create `requirejs-config.js` under your custom module, let say (`VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`)

In this js file,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/view/billing-address"
        }
    }
};
```

please note that `VENDOR_MODULE/js/view/billing-address` in this file you can write your changes (For testing purpose you can copy the original file and put some log)

After that perform `static-content:deploy` by executing the command from the magento2 root directory.

`php bin/magento s:s:d -f`

then clear the cache

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Thanks @Keyur Shah  & Ashish Viradiya. it working now. your both's answers work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a file that already exists that you are trying to override. Go to `http\app\design\frontend\company_name\theme` and in there you can create `Magento_Checkout`. Then as long as you get the exact file structure from where the `js` file is located within `module-checkout`. So say its within layout, create a layout folder and put it in there. Magento should use the new file instead of the default vendor file.